# Xamarin, TapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I can't understand why TapGestureRecognizer Command = "{Binding PointViewCommand}" CommandParameter = "{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" seems to overlap something. I grab the button there, the button clicks. If I put the TapGestureRecognizer into the first StackLayout after the ScrollView it works, but it doesn't suit me because there is a list and I need a click on a specific record.

```
<ScrollView IsVisible="{Binding IsSetActiveRoute}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSetActiveRoute}" InputTransparent="True">
        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding RouteListDoc.RowsRoute}" Padding="5">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="5"  OutlineColor="#c3c3c3" BackgroundColor="#F2FFFFE0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="125">
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PointViewCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" />
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large"/>
                                    <Label Text="Вікно доставки:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Start.Windows}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="80">
                                    <Image Source="arrow.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="Пал:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Finish.Pal}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="КГ:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Finish.KG}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="КМ:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Start.KM}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="125">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Finish.RoutePoint}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                    <Label Text="Вікно доставки:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Finish.Windows}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: if `PointViewCommand` is defined on the base VM and not on each individual row, you will need to use a relative binding

Comment: As per Jason's comment. Pls check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor. It will help.

Comment: Could you provide the `PointViewCommand` and what you have tried for the click on a specific record?

Comment: @Jason your answer very helped me. If you want, give full answer and I mark it like correct.